# Regular expression split and remove data

Tags: regex

I am not a specialist in Regex and this question may sound very easy.
I have a tab separated file with thousands of columns and the values in each column are like 2345:0 or 123:1

I would like to remove everything before the ":" and only keep 1 or 0

Can anyone point me to the right regular expression that I can use with see for example ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like in your case just a simple replace of `\d+:` with an empty string will do.

How that is done depends on your tool. With Perl you could:

```
perl -pe 's/\d+://g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following will capture the values after the colon (assumes a single digit):

```
/\d+\:(\d)/
```

Answer (score 1):

This will handle your tabs and capture a single number after the colon:

```
\s*\d+:(\d)
```